# OR mix with LIKE combine with a full outer join simulation is outputting unwanted results

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there is not a full outer JOIN for MySQL so I have to use different methods to achieve this kind of simulation so I found that method that works for me so this method works all the time but for some reason this is not working when I use OR with LIKE with this. I basically created a search engine for a modelling website which you can search for a specific model based by their first name or by their last name but I notice when I do something like this

```
WHERE models.first_name LIKE '%Jeda%' OR models.last_name LIKE '%Lee%' AND portfolio.profile_picture='yes' AND portfolio.status='yes'
```

It gives me this kind of result

[image: Example 1]

But really It should only be giving me this kind of result instead

[image: Example 2]

So why is it giving me additional results relating to the same model when I search by their first or by their last name? I thought by going based on profile_picture yes and status yes it will only give me one result, which I was expecting the red border one will only show. Why am I getting results not going based on profile_picture yes and status yes? I just feel like the way that this query is structured it is basically ignoring profile_picture yes and status yes so how can I get the result that I'm seeking? I just want the red border one to show only.

And this is my full query example

```
SELECT 

/*****<models section>*****/

models.id AS primary_id,
/**/

/*<targeted columns>*/
models.uid,
models.photo,
models.first_name,
models.last_name,
models.signature_name,
/*</targeted columns>*/

/*****</models section>*****/

/*****<portfolio section>*****/

/*<targeted columns>*/
portfolio.id,
portfolio.uid,
portfolio.type_of_media,
portfolio.path,
portfolio.profile_picture,
portfolio.status
/*</targeted columns>*/

/*****</portfolio section>*****/

/*****<models & portfolio section>*****/
FROM models LEFT JOIN portfolio 

/*<both tables are matched by this identical value>*/
ON models.uid = portfolio.uid
/*</both tables are matched by this identical value>*/

WHERE models.first_name LIKE '%Jeda%' OR models.last_name LIKE '%Lee%' AND portfolio.profile_picture='yes' AND portfolio.status='yes'
/*****</models & portfolio section>*****/

UNION 

SELECT

/*****<models section>*****/

/*<targeted columns>*/
models.id,
models.uid,models.photo,
models.first_name,
models.last_name,
models.signature_name,
/*</targeted columns>*/

/*****</models section>*****/

/*****<portfolio section>*****/

/*<targeted columns>*/
portfolio.id,
portfolio.uid,
portfolio.type_of_media,
portfolio.path,
portfolio.profile_picture,
portfolio.status
/*</targeted columns>*/

/*****</portfolio section>*****/

/*****<models & portfolio section>*****/
FROM models RIGHT JOIN portfolio 

/*<both tables are matched by this identical value>*/
ON models.uid = portfolio.uid
/*</both tables are matched by this identical value>*/

WHERE models.first_name LIKE '%Jeda%' OR models.last_name LIKE '%Lee%' AND portfolio.profile_picture='yes' AND portfolio.status='yes'

/*<using ORDER BY with the combined table generated 
primary key column with DESC direction as well>*/
ORDER BY primary_id DESC
/**/

/*****</models & portfolio section>*****/
```

Comment: Use parentheses: `WHERE (x=y OR x=z) AND foo=bar`

Comment: OMG thank you so much that works. How can parentheses cause that to work? If you don't mind me asking. Sorry i'm still a newbie to SQL.

Comment: If you don't use them, it gets evaluated as `WHERE x=y OR (x=z AND foo=bar)`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=Sql-Server-2014) for more info (link is for sql server, principle is the same. You can always search for `mysql operator precedence`). The big take home message is if you combine `AND` and `OR` **always** use parentheses!

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense now. Well thank you very much I really appreciate your help and your teaching.

Comment: You're very welcome. Spread the word and make everyone use parentheses.